# How do I make text not overlap layers or otherwise define a first page with sidebar and image-based footer?

Tags: context

I'm producing a letterhead and having rather a lot of trouble dropping all 7 necessary logos into the first page.

While I have quite successfully laid out the first page with setframedlayer and putting those layers into the background, I have not happened upon an adequate solution to the "margins problem."

The first page, using:

```
\setuplayout[% default layout for all the pages
    topspace=5mm, bottomspace=5mm,width=170mm, backspace=20mm]

\definelayout[1][backspace=20mm,
    width=115mm,
    topspace=20mm, top=0mm,
    header=40mm, footer=0mm
```

as well as quite a few layer commands produces:

[image: pretty first page]

But then it produces:

[image]

the margin continuing onto the second page, for the duration of the paragraph that has slopped over. While this is most likely a bug (or bad code on my part), the alternative is to impose two figures onto the first page holding the right sidebar and the bottom logos.

I am now trying to use tricks from the Tricks manual to do floats and am [failing](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) utterly. I have attempted this on both the TeXLive 2012 version as well as the latest standalone version.

Comment: Can someone tag this layers, and/or add other tags to fit? I'm not entirely sure of the tag ontology over here.

Comment: Superping me in chat if I should improve my question, please.

Comment: This is a limitation of TeX which first typesets paragraphs and then breaks them into a page. So the width of a paragraph cannot change in the middle.

Answer (score 3):

The sidebar should be a placed float:

```
\placefigure[none, right, margin, top]{}{
\externalfigure[faims.jpg]
                 [width=50mm]
                 {
                 \color[faimsblue]{\setupwhitespace[small] http://www.fedarch.org}}
    \framed[width=50mm, frame=off, align={stretch, verytolerant, hz, hanging}, ]{\tfxx\setupinterlinespace[line=3.78ex]\sc\color[faimsblue]{Contributors: Australian Heritage}}}
```

The bottom should be a *layer* sitting in a `\setupfooter[state=empty]` which provides for a blank footer space (so that your second-page footers can be customized.

That produces:

[image]