# ConTexT \placefigure locations not working as I expect

Tags: floats, context

I would like help to use ConTexT’s \placefigure. ConTexT seems to ignore some location options. How can I get it to use the options? I’m using ConText LMTX, the current version.

I found this post from 10 years ago: [How do I make text not overlap layers or otherwise define a first page with sidebar and image-based footer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66006/how-do-i-make-text-not-overlap-layers-or-otherwise-define-a-first-page-with-side/66018#66018) . The location options in the first answer: `[none, right, margin, top]` seemed to work 10 years ago. They put the image on the right, in the margin and at the top.

I pasted that first answer from that post into this MWE:

```
\showframe
\setuplayout[backspace=20mm, width=100mm, topspace=20mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=250mm, margindistance=10mm, rightmargin=50mm]

\starttext  
\input{knuth}

\placefigure[none, right, margin, top]{}{
\externalfigure[faims.jpg]
                 [width=50mm]
                 {
                 \color[faimsblue]{\setupwhitespace[small] http://www.fedarch.org}}
                 \framed[width=50mm, frame=off, align={stretch, verytolerant, hz, hanging}, ]{\tfxx\setupinterlinespace[line=3.78ex]\sc\color[faimsblue]{Contributors: Australian Heritage}}}    
\input{knuth}
\input{knuth}   

\stoptext
```

But when I run it, it ignores the `margin` and `top` location options. See screenshot below. I tried it on the online ConTexT live and got the same result.

How can I get ConTexT to use the options `margin` and `top`?
[image: MWE example pdf]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use `\start` and `\stop` versions of the environments. Maybe the `location=margin` solves your problem? I also changed some other smaller things.

```
\showframe
\setuplayout[backspace=20mm, width=100mm, topspace=20mm, header=0mm, footer=0mm, height=250mm, margindistance=10mm, rightmargin=50mm]

\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\setupwhitespace[medium]

\setupcaptions[
    style={\switchtobodyfont[small]},
]

\starttext  
\samplefile{ward}

\startbuffer
This is a caption to the top cow (the best?). Moo! I liek milk!
\stopbuffer

\startplacefigure[location={margin,nonumber},title={\getbuffer}]
\externalfigure[cow][width=50mm]
\stopplacefigure    

\samplefile{tufte}

\startbuffer
\blue \samplefile{ward}
\stopbuffer

\startplacefigure[location={margin,nonumber},title={\getbuffer}]
\externalfigure[cow][width=50mm]
\stopplacefigure    

\input{knuth}   
\stoptext
```

[image: figures in the margin]

Comment: Thanks for that and for rewriting it, it helps me understand how to write ConTexT. When I add `bottom` to the location of the second cow it stays in the same place. I suspect that's just how it is.